# Upgrading a custom theme through the Dashboard

Tags: theme-development, themes, customization, upgrade

I can't seem to upgrade my custom theme. Whenever I try to uploaded a new package, all I get is:

> Unpacking the package…
>   Installing the theme…
>   Destination folder
>   already exists. /wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/
>   Theme install failed.

I've searched and all I can find is people recommending upgrading over FTP. Sadly, I don't have FTP access right now, but also using FTP appears to be a dirty solution. I can obviously delete and re-install the theme, but that seems very dirty, too.

How can I update a theme through the Dashboard?

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Comment: What you are trying to do and what you are requesting are both horrendously bad practice, and should never be done. Though it wasn't me that downvoted

Comment: @TomJNowell Then what's the Good Practice way of upgrading a theme? I'm all ears!

Comment: "...what's the Good Practice way of upgrading a theme?"-- My opinion... FTP. I wouldn't consider that a "dirty" solution and it is the only way I ever update a production server.

Comment: Tom - Why is that bad practice? Without an explanation, your response seems to fall into opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails because there is already a theme with that name on the server.

**So the obvious solution is to remove the theme before you upload the new version.**

If you're wanting to use an update mechanism like the theme repo, but on a custom theme, there are udpater classes you can add, such as this one:

https://github.com/UCF/Theme-Updater

That particular one uses github as its source, but there are various alternatives that use other sources

A few notes for anyone else with similar issues, pitfalls of using the backend to install and manage code:

- Doing this is **incredibly bad practice**
- If your host won't give you FTP access, your host must be pretty awful. I strongly recommend you switch providers.
- You should not be able to add or install plugins via the dashboard, this indicates those folders are writable and is a **massive** security risk
- If you have made a mistake in your theme ( it happens to the best of us ) and the functions.php has a syntax error etc, your site will be dead. You won't be able to login via the backend to edit the files or upload a new version or switch to a working theme.

Similar if not identical issues apply to plugins also.

Comment: Tom, could you please elaborate on the ability to add plugins via the dashboard? I guess it's something almost everyone does.

Comment: @rrikesh you can add new plugins via the add new link in the admin menu, and either search for or install, but everything I mentioned for themes applies to plugins too, although its a tiny bit safer with plugins because you can just rename the plugins folder if everything goes wrong to get your dashboard back

Comment: @TomJNowell I think you misunderstand my question. Obviously I can delete the theme and re-upload it, but this is a pretty horrible way to go about things. I'm looking for a Good Practice way of updating a theme through the Dashboard, like TwentyTen has, without altering the Core, obv. Plug-ins and themes have the ability to update, don't they?

Comment: Oooh, those work via the theme repository, you mean something like this? https://github.com/UCF/Theme-Updater

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks! (Although I'm surprised and saddened that this functionality isn't part of WordPress by default! Weird.) You should update your answer. Thanks.

Comment: If you're okay with it being on github? There are other updaters in this vein that dont use github

Comment: I've amended my answer. Perhaps you could ammend your question a little as i see it's being close voted? Making if clearer this is what you'd like would undo some of that and possibly even get the downvote reversed

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question. No need to put the delete and reinstall option in your answer -- I knew that! :)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt, a good Answer is a canonical (complete) one, that will help future visitors with the same doubt ;) . . . *maybe both you folks could clean this comment thread?*

Comment: I've cleaned up my comments prior to the comment about misunderstanding, if Django can do the same